# How to get same MailItem unique property in different outlook client

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an outlook add-in. In the outlook add-in, there is a functionality of uploading email with MSG extension on the cloud. I have marked that email with some identification in outlook.

My add-in was installed in two clients with different email addresses. Like, a1@a1.com and b1@b1.com.

Both the client having the same email in the inbox. Like, To a1@a1.com, b1@b1.com & Subject: Testing Email

If one client filed this email on the cloud then the second client automatically displays it is filed with the same uploaded marker which was display in the first client.

So, for that, I want some unique property of email which will be the same for both the clients.

Actually, I am thinking about the below logic. If one client filed an email on the cloud then My add-in will save common property value in the cloud database. In the second client was found the same property value in the cloud database then It will automatically display uploaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For sent and received items you can use the [PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaginternetmessageid-canonical-property) property which contains a string corresponds to the message ID field as specified in [RFC2822]. Exchange sets that property for all messages created in the store, but you will not necessarily find the property set on messages in the cached store (until they are sent).

> The message ID is like a digital fingerprint of a message and is usually added by the mail server that sends your message out on behalf of your mail client. The message ID looks a bit like a really long and cryptic email address; here's an example of a Message-ID for an email sent from Gmail:

```
Message-ID: <CAKBqNfyKo+ZXtkz6DUAHw6FjmsDjWDB-pvHkJy6kwO82jTbkNA@mail.gmail.com>
```

> The text after the @ symbol generally refers to the server that is sending the email out to the world on your behalf, and the part before the @ symbol is a unique key or identifier according to that mail server. So, by making every server responsible for setting its own ID before the @ symbol, and including the name of the server that did the setting after the @ symbol, we've basically got a unique fingerprint for every email message in the world - more than 150 billion a day!

Also, you may try to use other mail properties such as `Subject`, `To`, `From` and etc. according to your needs. You even can add your own user property to mail items.